# How to pass parameter to async.reflect functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have to post a bunch of requests to the same endpoint with different payloads. The payloads are all in a loop and I felt `async.parallelLimit` used alongwith `async.reflect` would solve the issue. But I ran into the closure and scope issue with this. I know how to address this with a `setTimeout`using the third parameter. Below is my snippet of code,

```
var tasks = [];
for ( i in items  ){
  if ( items[i] ){
    tasks.push(async.reflect(function(callback) {
      axios.post(storeEndpoint, items[i])
      .then(callback)
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log('error', err);
      });
    }));
  } 
}
async.parallelLimit(tasks, 10, (err, results) => {
  console.log("res: ", results.length);
  console.log('done');
});
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example